# In function there is block of code after if in curly brackets , I want to know what could be the output

Tags: javascript

In function there is block of code after if in curly brackets , I want to know what could be the output. Surprisingly output is 1000.

```js
function calculateTotalAmount (vip) {
  var amount = 0
  if (vip) {
    var amount = 1
  }
  { // more crazy blocks!
    var amount = 100
    {
      var amount = 1000
      }
  }  
  return amount
}

console.log(calculateTotalAmount(true))
```

Comment: It is explained in the documentation on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block

Answer (score 2):

If you want to return differents values based on your `vip` parameter, you need to put an `else` statement right after your first block.

Answer (score 1):

We normally use curly braces to organise the code unless it is a `if-else` block. The same happens in your code. That code is equivalent to:

```js
function calculateTotalAmount(vip) {
  var amount = 0
  if (vip) {
    var amount = 1
  }
  var amount = 100
  var amount = 1000
  return amount
}

console.log(calculateTotalAmount(true))
```

So in your code you are overwritting the value of `amount` in each successive line. That is why you get `1000` as a final output.

Comment: I was bit confuse about { // more crazy blocks!
    var amount = 100
    {
      var amount = 1000
      }
  }
above code because that has no object or anything but thanks

Comment: @VishalPachpande the curly braces on your context is simply used to organize the code and nothing else.

Comment: @VishalPachpande glad to help you by any means